# Typescript - types from d.ts file are not found

Tags: typescript

How the types from `d.ts` files are resolved?

As per my understanding types from `d.ts` files should be automatically available, without having to explicitly import them, but they are not.

These 2 files are side by side in the same folder:

*foo.d.ts*

```
  export type Foo = {
    bar: string
  }
```

*foo.ts*

```
const getFoo = (): Foo => {
  return {
    bar: 'Foo'
  }
}
```

**However, having an error** `TS2304: Cannot find name 'Foo'.`

My *tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "typeRoots": [ "./types", "./node_modules/@types"],
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "types/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "typings"]
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, you should declare `Foo` type inside `foo.ts`.
If you want to declare some global types, create `global.d.ts` or `globals.d.ts` file in the root of app and put there all global types. If you still want to create `foo.d.ts`, you should probably have `foo.js` file. In this case `foo.d.ts` will  extend exported values from `foo.js`. See how it works in material-ui repo: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/packages/material-ui/src/Accordion

Comment: Not really. I find resolving d.ts files a bit confusing still after reading that. In the accepted answer is said: *"let's say, my-module.js, if there is a my-module.d.ts next to it, then TypeScript will include its content"*. Does that mean d.ts file with the same name should be automatically included? Like in my case foo.ts should include automatically foo.d.ts?

Comment: you can include `d.ts` file if you are working with pure js files and you want to provide some typings. IF you are working with ts files, you should not use d.ts files - at least you should not create them manually. There is once case when you need to create manualy d.ts - it is when you want to declare global type. Lets say you want to extends `DOcument` interface or any built in type

Comment: Oh. So `d.ts` files are only for adding typings for `js` files? Well that's confusing. I would have found that convenient for separating types from actual implementation, however I stand corrected, that they're not meant for that.

Comment: It is up to you how you want to separate your types from other code. For instance in my team, we are adding `*.types.ts`  prefix to the name of the file

Comment: Okay I see. And then manually import them where needed?

Comment: @RootNode yes, exactly

Comment: Okay I see. It seems I've understood `.d.ts` files completely wrong. I thought that they were a convenient way to declare types without a need to manually import them where needed. But okay now I know better. Thanks.